# Методы из другого класса

Tags: ооп, java

Допустим есть класс `Methods.java` без конструктора который содержите в себе различные методы.
Есть еще класс `Main.java`, в нем я хочу использоваться методы из класса `Methods.java`. Как можно это сделать, кроме использования `extends`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто:

```
 Methods mymethods = new Methods();
 mymethods.myPublicMethodInClassMethods();
```

или, если метод статический, то объявляете его прямо в секции, где Вы делаете import других пакетов.

```
 import static packageName.ClassName.staticMemberName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Методы публичные? Сконструируйте класс конструктором по умолчанию (`new Methods()`) и пользуйтесь. Если методы к тому же ещё и статические, даже экземпляр класса не нужен.

Comment: возможно ТС просто не знает о статических методах.